# Jquery canvas cloud plugin - How to style canvas elements with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas, cloud

i found this nice jquery plugin
http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php

**the description says:** The canvas is a part of the page, so you can style it with CSS - e.g. to add a border, margins

Ok, but is it possible to give each tag a different font-size (like in the most tagClouds)?

Comment: I don't think it is possible from css. You have to modify the js code that generates this tag cloud. As I can see you can pass parameters to the plugin about the font-size (textHeight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you've linked to says it supports [weighted tags](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas-weighted.php) from version 1.6, is this what you want?

Comment: I must be blind! Thank you very much!